# Improving a custom tensorflow model - freezing and unfreezing only select layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have written a model to add fully connected layers to a pre-trained model. The identity of the pre-trained model can be selected or will default to ResNet50. My code runs, but if training is set to False, all of the training parameters of the entire model are frozen (not just the pre-trained model). I'm concerned that there is something wrong with my approach. I'm wondering how I can fix this.

This is my model:

```
class build_transfer_model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,n=32,tmodel='ResNet50',**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.inputs = tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28,28,3))
        self.resize = tf.keras.layers.Resizing(n,n)
        self.tmodel = eval(tmodel+'(include_top=False, input_shape=(n,n,3),weights=\'imagenet\')')
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='linear', kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        
        
    def call(self,inputs,trainable=False):
        if trainable:
            self.tmodel.trainable = True #unfreezes base model
            for layer in self.tmodel: #freezes batch normalization layers
                if (isinstance(layer, tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization)):
                    layer.trainable = False
        else:
            self.tmodel.trainable = False
        
        X = self.inputs(inputs)
        X = self.resize(X)
        X = self.tmodel(X)
        X = self.flatten(X)
        X = self.hidden1(X)
        X = self.dropout(X)
        X = self.hidden2(X)
        X = self.dropout(X)
        return self.hidden3(X)
```

I've isolated the issue to the training = False case as the model appears to work well in the training = True case. Any advice is much appreciated. Thanks!